# How to determine the type of the workload of a program?

Tags: performance-testing, perf

Assume the following scenario: a developer gives you his Java application and you want to determine the app's resource requirements:

- does it consume a lot of CPU?
- does it allocate a lot of memory?
- does it read/write a lot to disk?
- does it consume network bandwidth?

What are the indicators one should look for to get the picture about the app's requirements? One can run the given app as many times as it is required.

What I've found is the [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) tool on Linux. It can measure literally everything (cpu cycles, cache misses, page faults, 
branch misses, different disk operations, memory allocation ...).

Is there any methodology that could be applied?

Thanks!

Comment: Run it on an otherwise-idle machine and look at CPU/memory with `top`, and disk + network I/O with [`dstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat) or `vmstat`.  `perf` is great, but doesn't really do memory-footprint profiling.  You could use `perf` to see how hyperthreading-friendly the program is, maybe.  (Lots of branch misses / low IPC means it can probably share a core with another thread without much problem, unless the low IPC was from cache misses and it will only get worse with two threads competing for L1d / L1i / L2 cache.)

Comment: Has the developer performed any local profiling and monitoring at all?   Is this question on a single user basis or a multiple user basis?

Comment: Such broad questions are usually answered with system monitoring tools, which makes this question kind of off-topic. But it's also rather broad.

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally you should go for a [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), this way you will not only able to measure CPU/RAM/Network/Disk consumption, but detect "heavy" methods, largest objects, etc.
2. If you don't have a profiler tool you can use [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html) which provides basically the same functionality but the output will be limited comparing to the special profiling tools.
3. You can use monitoring tools built into your operating system like [Windows Performance Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicsnav-2016/dn271687(v=nav.90)) or [nmon](http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php) for Linux
4. And last but not the least you can consider [sigar](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) which is free and open source system information gatherer and monitor. The easiest way of collecting and plotting sigar metrics is [PerfMon](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)